# PCA formulation: Find the best rank-$k$ subspace of $d$-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning

Finding the best rank-$k$ subspace of $d$-dimensional space can be interpreted as the Principle Component Analysis (PCA) problem provided that the goal of optimization is minimizing the error in the sense of variance.

Assume we have access to the data sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$, prove that the first problem is equivalent to the second one:

$$
\hat{U_n}= \arg \min \sum_{l=1}^{n}\big\|x_l-\mathcal{P}_U(x_l)\big\|_2^2 \tag{1}
$$
such that
$$
U \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k},U^TU=I_k
$$

$$
\hat{U_n}= \arg \min \|X_n-UU^TX_n\|_F^2 \tag{2}
$$
such that
$$
U \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k},U^TU=I_k
$$

where $I_k$ is Identity matrix, ${P}_U=UU^T$ is a projection matrix, $X_n=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 &\cdots& x_n\end{bmatrix}$ is a matrix of data, $\|\cdot\|_F$ is Frobenius norm, i.e. $\|A\|_F=\sqrt{\text{Trace}(A^TA)}$.

Comment: PCA is not "best" subspace. It is subspace that orthogonally minimizes error the most in sense of the variance. There exist very many other senses to minimize errors.

Comment: You are right about the PCA. Those optimization problems are defined to find the best subspace which has the minimum variance for the error which is PCA.

Comment: @  mathreadler: I modified the question's statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start with $\|x_l-\mathcal{P}_U(x_l)\big\|_2^2$. It can be written as
$$
\|x_l-\mathcal{P}_U(x_l)\big\|_2^2 =(x_l^T-x_l^TUU^T)^T(x_l-UU^Tx_l)=
$$

$$
=x_l^Tx_l-x_l^TUU^Tx_l-x_l^TUU^Tx_l+x_l^TUU^TUU^Tx_l
$$

since $U^TU=I_k$

$$
=x_l^Tx_l-x_l^TUU^Tx_l-x_l^TUU^Tx_l+x_l^TUU^Tx_l=x_l^Tx_l-x_l^TUU^Tx_l
$$

$$
\sum_{l=1}^{n}\big\|x_l-\mathcal{P}_U(x_l)\big\|_2^2 =\sum_{l=1}^{n} (x_l^Tx_l-x_l^TUU^Tx_l)
$$

since the value of the sum is scalar we can write

$$
\sum_{l=1}^{n} (x_l^Tx_l-x_l^TUU^Tx_l)=\text{Trace}(\sum_{l=1}^{n} (x_l^Tx_l-x_l^TUU^Tx_l))= \text{Trace}(
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^T & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2^T & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n^T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n
\end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^T & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2^T & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n^T
\end{bmatrix}
UU^T
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n
\end{bmatrix}) \tag{1}
$$

On the other hand,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^T \\
 x_2^T \\
 \cdots \\
 x_n^T \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^Tx_1 & x_1^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_1^Tx_n \\
x_1^Tx_2 & x_1^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_2^Tx_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
x_n^Tx_1 & x_n^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_n^Tx_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that

$$
\text{Trace}(
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^Tx_1 & x_1^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_1^Tx_n \\
x_1^Tx_2 & x_1^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_2^Tx_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
x_n^Tx_1 & x_n^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_n^Tx_n
\end{bmatrix})=
\text{Trace}(
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^T & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2^T & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n^T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n
\end{bmatrix})
$$

And,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^T \\
 x_2^T \\
 \cdots \\
 x_n^T \\
\end{bmatrix}
UU^T
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^TUU^T \\
 x_2^TUU^T \\
 \cdots \\
 x_n^TUU^T \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^TUU^Tx_1 & x_1^TUU^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_1^TUU^Tx_n \\
x_1^TUU^Tx_2 & x_1^TUU^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_2^TUU^Tx_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
x_n^TUU^Tx_1 & x_n^TUU^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_n^TUU^Tx_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that

$$
\text{Trace}(
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^TUU^Tx_1 & x_1^TUU^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_1^TUU^Tx_n \\
x_1^TUU^Tx_2 & x_1^TUU^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_2^TUU^Tx_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
x_n^TUU^Tx_1 & x_n^TUU^Tx_2 & \cdots & x_n^TUU^Tx_n
\end{bmatrix})=
\text{Trace}(
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1^T & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2^T & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n^T
\end{bmatrix}
UU^T
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n
\end{bmatrix}) 
$$

Hence,

$$
(1)=\text{Trace}(X^TX-X^TUU^TX)
$$

$$
=\text{Trace}(X^TX-X^TUU^TX-X^TUU^TX+X^TUU^TUU^TX)=\text{Trace}((X-UU^TX)^T(X-UU^TX))=\big\|X-UU^TX\big\|_F^2
$$